# Bash script - string with spaces as a single argument

Tags: bash, shell, sh, zsh

This isn't all I'm doing in my real application, but it boils down to this:

I have a function that returns stuff with a space in it. I want to be able to call the function and have the contents be interpreted as a single argument, and I want to do this in the cleanest / shortest way possible.

For example:

```
sp() {
    echo "hello world"
}
echo `sp`         # two arguments to echo, BAD
echo $(sp)        # two arguments to echo, BAD
echo "$(sp)"      # one argument to echo, GOOD, but this takes a lot of characters
```

Is there any shorter / cleaner way to achieve what I want to do? I'm looking for something that's easier to type (4 extra characters is a lot). Perhaps some features that are not part of `sh`, but maybe `bash` or `zsh`? This sounds horrible, but because this is going to be typed into an interactive session, so perhaps some way to hook into the shell and modify the command line before it is executed?

Comment: In Bash and POSIX-compliant shells, the third alternative is the shortest reliable way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zsh will do what you want out-of-the-box -- in zsh, `foo $bar` treats the expansion of `$bar` as a single argument by default, as opposed to string-splitting and glob-expanding unless it's double-quoted.

That said, it violates the POSIX sh standard by doing so, and you should be wary of learning bad habits: I personally used zsh until I discovered that it was making me sloppy when trying to write scripts for other shells.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to evaluate a function (that will return different things, so I can't just store the results in a variable).

Is it possible to do anything similar with a function?

Comment: Sounds like the question you asked doesn't exactly match the one you wanted to ask. Anyhow -- yes, you can do that. One approach is to accept the place to store results as an argument. Another approach is to return a NUL-delimited stream, and read from that in the caller; yet another is to use hardcoded global variables for your output. If you want more details on any of these, ask in a separate question (if you can't find one that already answers it on the site).

Comment: @fwenom ...continuing re: said unrelated question asked as a followup (*grumble*), see also BashFAQ #006: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Assigning_indirect.2Freference_variables

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

I missed that variables could actually be defined like x="$(run some function here)" and that they would be re-evaluated every time you wrote $x.

Comment: @fwenom, I'm glad this answer proved useful, but still a bit shaky in terms of understanding how you're using it; the example you just gave only runs the function once. See BashFAQ #50 to better understand caveats and limitations around storing code in scalar variables: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: I'm using it to save on typing extra characters in the shell. I have a variable (which is actually a function as defined above) that returns different things based on context. I want to be able to use things like `cp files... $x` and have the files be copied to the location pointed to by evaluating some function. When I define `x=$(f)`, it's easier to type `$x` than `"$(f)"` to prevent expansion.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to call the function and have the contents be interpreted as a single argument, and I want to do this in the cleanest / shortest way possible.

The cleanest and shorted way possible is to enclose your arguments around quotes to prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html) and possible [pathname expansion (now named filename expansion in 4.3)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) however there's a workaround if you only plan to run your scripts on Zsh or Bash.

In Bash, you can simply just disable word splitting with `IFS=`. You can also disable pathname expansion with `shopt -s -o noglob` or `set -f`. With sensible application this can actually be a good practice for advanced scripters if they know what they're doing.

Of course with word splitting disabled you can no longer do `for x in $something; do`. But that doesn't matter anyway since unless pathname expansion is disabled, that form is not commendable. You can however use `IFS=<separators> read -rd '' -a array <<< "$something"; for x in "${array[@]}"; do` as a better alternative.

With pathname expansion disabled you can still use `compgen` (applies `extglob` and `dotglob` as well when enabeld):

```
readarray -t files < <(compgen -G '*')
```

Or

```
IFS='\n' read -rd ''  -a files < <(compgen -G '*')
```

But that's not going to be perfect enough for filenames with newlines as conservative parties would say. So you can use a generator function:

```
function generate {
    local RESTORE=$(shopt -p -o noglob) IFS=
    shopt -u -o noglob
    __=($1)
    eval "$RESTORE"
}

generate '*'

for file in "${__[@]}"; do
    :
done
```

This is good if you don't do pathname expansion often.

And there's one last thing: `"$*"` and `"${var[*]}"` would no longer expand with space as a separator. So like when having a custom separator, merging arrays to a string is easy with `eval`:

```
IFS=' ' eval 'merged="${var[*]}"'
```

And all of these can be done safely by inserting the rules at the beginning of the script.

```
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] || exit  ## You may use a block instead and insert a message if you like.
[[ BASH_VERSINFO -ge 4 ]] || exit  ## If you need `readarray` or other 4.0+ stuffs.
IFS=
shopt -s -o noglob
```

With that you can now safely use `do_something $x`.

Now watch how these ideas go to posing online wikis later ;)

<sub>*Like I said, this is for advanced users. People who care much about promotion and denounce possibly misleading practices to newbies would probably not want this. So as explicitly noted, stay away from this if you have an opposing approach or perception. No need to bash with "obvious" remarks.*</sub>

Comment: Since when does a "for experts only" line only give one free rein to promote code that would make handling the filename `/tmp/$(rm -rf /)/foo` hazardous? It's certainly _possible_ to quote content for safe evaluation using `printf '%q '`; if you did so here, I'd have no qualm with the eval-based example.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You have such a good comment that I don't follow you at all. Perhaps try to be more specific?

Comment: And I'm not promoting anything. I'm giving a solution as required. On the contrary you are the one promoting your unwarranted scripting philosophies.

Comment: I haven't contributed a single change to the Wooledge wiki in years; if anyone is appropriating your code without credit, that wouldn't be me. That said -- it appears that you're correct with respect to the usage of `eval` in this context. `eval 'merged="${var[*]}"'` is indeed safe, and my contrary comment mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for interactive use, perhaps you could use an auxiliary function to do the quoting for you.  Something like:

```
$ func() { for arg; do echo "arg: $arg"; done; }
$ q() { cmd=$1; shift; $cmd "$*"; }
$ sp() { echo hello world; }
$ f="$(sp)"
$ echo $f
hello world
$ func $f
arg: hello
arg: world
$ q func $f
arg: hello world
$ q func `sp`
arg: hello world
```